# crystal reports not working on clients machine.Dispaly "Application stopped working"

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Hai Im working on c# visual studio 2010 and sql server 2008.I have used crsytal reports in my  program.I am able to access the crstal reports on my computer but if i go on my client server run the program and  if i click the crystal reports it displays "Application stopped working"

Comment: Is CR iruntime nstalled on the target machine?

Comment: yes ..its is installed on clients machine